# Pointer to variadic template static function. How?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I have a code:

```
class Factory
{
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    static void testFunc(Args&& ...args)
    {
        cout << "inside function";
    }
};
```

Is it possible to create a pointer to **testFunc**?
All I can do is to define it like this:

```
// main
void(*pFunc)() = &Factory::testFunc;
pFunc();
```

This works, but I can't pass variable number of arguments, like this:

```
void(*pFunc)(WHAT_TO_TYPE_HERE?) = &Factory::testFunc;
pFunc(10, false, 'a', 11.5);
```

P.S.: with ellipsis (...) everythings works.

Comment: `testFunc` isn't a function, but a function template. Therefore, a pointer to a (member) function cannot point to `testFunc`.

Comment: @chris But it works for pointer to argumentless function.

Comment: If with (...) everything works, then what is the question?

Comment: @zoska Because I don't know how to pass ... parameters to another function.

Comment: But you wrote, that "everything works".

Comment: @zoska Sorry, my bad.

Comment: If you consider `f` to be a "pointer" then yes: `Factory f;`

Comment: Can you identify the problem that led you to want to store a pointer to a `template` function?  In general, it is usually a good idea to sketch the "one level higher" motivation behind a problem as well as the problem.

Comment: @nikitablack, Yes, and it works with a pointer to an instantiation, of `testFunc`, too. It still won't work if that "argumentless function" is actually a function template.

Comment: The problem is `pFunc` needs George Clinton in order to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a pointer to `testFunc`?

The declaration of `testFunc` defines a family of functions, parameterized by `Args`. Each of those functions will have its own memory address. So you can only have a pointer to a particular one of the functions defined by `testFunc`, such as `testFunc<int, double>` or `testFunc<>`.

Instead of writing the following to get a pointer to the 0-argument overload of `testFunc`

```
void(*pFunc)() = &Factory::testFunc;
```

you should be writing

```
void(*pFunc)() = &Factory::testFunc<>;
```

because `Factory::testFunc` without the `<>` is an overload set, not a function.

Comment: Thank you. I see the logic. But anyway, I can't declare pointer to function taking, say, **int**. This is not compile: `void(*pFunc)(int) = &Factory::testFunc<int>;
 pFunc(10);`

Comment: @nikitablack That's because the signature of `pFunc` is wrong. It should be this: `void (*pFunc) (int&&)`

Comment: Actually, you went too far. THe magic is using the identifier in a context where it uniquely identifies a specific function. (You omitted that originally. If the context is there, normal overload-resolution, including template-argument-inferrence, will get it done.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to:

```
void(*pFunc)(WHAT_TO_TYPE_HERE?) = &Factory::testFunc;
pFunc(10, false, 'a', 11.5);
```

is:

```
void (*pFunc)(int&&, bool&&, char&&, double&&) = 
    &Factory::testFunc<int, bool, char, double>;
```

Since `testFunc` defines a whole family of functions, you can't just take one function pointer to all of them. You have to say which one you're taking a function pointer to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. You just need to:

1. Instantiate the static function and takes its address (`testFunc` is just a *template* (in the real sense of the definition of the word), you need to use that template to build a real function (which is what `<>` does; it specifies all the pieces the compiler needs to use the template to build a real function)
2. Make a function pointer that takes the right arguments (remember, you're using `&&` in the template function)

[Here's a demo](http://ideone.com/tcsn9o):

```
#include <iostream>

// Ignore this printHelper stuff; it just prints out the arguments
static void printHelper()
{
}

template <typename T>
static void printHelper(T&& arg)
{
    std::cout << arg;
}

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
static void printHelper(T&& arg, Args&& ...args)
{
    std::cout << arg << ", ";
    printHelper(args...);
}

class Factory
{
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    static void testFunc(Args&& ...args)
    {
        std::cout << "inside function; args are: ";
        printHelper(args...);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    void (*pFunc1)() = &Factory::testFunc<>;
    pFunc1();

    void (*pFunc2)(int&&, char&&, double&&) = &Factory::testFunc<int, char, double>;
    pFunc2(1, 'a', 3.14);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a pointer to one function pointer to one instance of the template function that can be called with exactly those arguments:

```
void(*pFunc)(WHAT_TO_TYPE_HERE?) = &Factory::testFunc;
pFunc(10, false, 'a', 11.5);
```

then `WHAT_TO_TYPE_HERE` becomes

```
void(*pFunc)(int&&, bool&&, char&&, double&&) = &Factory::testFunc;
pFunc(10, false, 'a', 11.5);
```

Now, a downside is that we have fixed the rvalue/lvalue status of each argument in the function pointer, which is annoying.

So this helper is useful:

```
template<class Sig, class Function>
struct testfunc_as_function_ptr;
template<class R, class...Args>
struct testfunc_as_function_ptr {
  R(*)(Args...) operator()() const {
    return [](Args...args){ return Factory::testFunc(std::forward<Args>(args)...); };
  }
};
```

which is pretty obtuse, but does give you:

```
void(*pFunc)(int,bool,char,double) = testfunc_as_function_ptr<void(int, bool, char, double)>{}();
```

where you can pick a signature, and if the signature is compatible with calling `testFunc` it works.

However, if you want a pointer to the ENTIRE template function, and not just an instance of it:

This is the nary dispatch problem.

The first thing to realize is that templates are not "things" in C++.  templates **make** things.  A template class makes classes -- a template function makes functions.

A function template is not a function.  It is a template to produce functions.

So your `template<class...Args> void testFunc(Args&& ...args)` is not a function.  It is instructions on how to produce a function -- in fact, instructions how to produce any number of different functions.  These functions are all "overloads" of each other.

For functions, when you call them, the overload is automatically generated from the arguments, then overload resolution kicks in (possibly eliminating the generated overload from consideration, if for example there is a non-template produced function that matches just as well).

A pointer is (mostly) a runtime construct, and a pointer to a function must point to an actual "thing" (an actual function).  It cannot point to a template.

Now, `void testFunc(...)` is an actual function.  The same function is created and run regardless of what arguments are passed to it.  So you can have a pointer to `void testFunc(...)`.

So while we cannot have a pointer to a template, you can create a pointer to a construct (an object) that can dispatch to a template.  This, however, requires that the dispatch be determined at the point that the construct is created, and calling that construct can only reach those per-determined instantiations.

This is a kind of nary dispatch -- which overload you call is determined by the arguments you pass to the function.

C++ does not support storing a code generating template in an object.  You can store it in a type (a class), but not in an actual object.

We can often fix this problem by realizing that the body of the template function may not need everything about the `Args...` in general.  For example, maybe the body of the template function only needs to learn how to turn a given `Arg` into a string?

In that case, we can create an interface that looks like:

```
struct printable { virtual std::string to_string() const = 0; ~printable(); };

using printer = void(*)(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<printable>>);
```

and `printer` is a pointer to a function that takes a `vector` of `printable` pointers.  We can then write code that takes an arbitrary type `T` and makes it `printable`.

This does require knowing what about the function we are trying to produce needs to know about the `Args...`.

You can go as far as making your function pointer be a pointer to a type-erased iterable range to something equivalent to a `boost::any`, then have the body determine what types is actually needs and do introspection.  This is the type-safe equivalent to the `void (*)(...)` C-style variardic, where the called function has to do all the type-gymnastics to make sure things work manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `&Factory::testFunc` refers to an overload set, not a single function.

Whether that overload-set includes (or consists) of a template-function or not is immaterial, the ambiguity means the compiler does not know what to do.

Just `static_cast` to pointer to function of the wanted type (or use it in another context making the needed type obvious), like this:

```
void(*pFunc)() = &Factory::testFunc;
f( (void(*)())&Factory::testFunc); // static_cast to get the right overload
```

See on coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13571ddf095df15f

Of course, because it is a template-function, you might be able to pick a single function out of the overload-set by explicitly specifying arguments as well, like this:

```
void(*pFunc)() = &Factory::testFunc<>;
```

Comment: Is this really well defined behavior: `void (*pFunc3)(std::string&&, std::string&&, int&&, int&&) = (void(*)(std::string&&, std::string&&, int&&, int&&))&Factory::testFunc;
pFunc3("Hello", "world", 42, 13);`??? How does the compiler know to instantiate `Factory::testFunc<std::string, std::string, int, int>`? Does the cast itself instantiate the function?

Comment: @Cornstalks: Simple. It does its normal overload-resolution-thing (that's how it is defined), and the unique best match is that template-instantiation. Which will lead to it being ODR-used (if used in a potentially evaluated context), and thus implicitly instantiated.

Comment: So does the cast itself cause the instantiation to occur? I guess I'm just confused how that instantiation comes into existence so it can play a role in overload resolution. Anyway, here, have a +1 for teaching me something new.

Comment: @Cornstalks: The overload set consists of all template (at least those not removed by SFINAE), and all non-template *declarations*. If a single best match is found, that's the one wanted, otherwise we have a compilation-error (ambiguity or no match). And if that use was in a potentially evaluated context (for example neither in `sizeof` nor `decltype`), we have ODR-use and thus implicit instantiation if needed (no explicit instantiation nor extern declaration). There's a prominent example of a function-template which must never be instantiated: `std::declval`.